# How do you find out if any select menu have been put into focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select-menu

I am trying to limit query calls using a function that will place edited items into an object then pass them to a PHP script to update only the edited information. In this case I am using jQuery's change() function, however I can not find a pseudo selector for select menu's (ie. :input, input:checkbox). The only idea I have left is to add a class to all the select menu's and go from there like so:

```
$(":input, input:checkbox, .selectedMenu").change(function() {
    //Some Code here
});
```

I have checked all over and cannot find any information on this. Would this be the best way or is there an alternative?

Problem: How can you find out if any select menu has been put into focus using a pseudo selector or anything on those lines?

Comment: `$('select').focus(function(){  })` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select` is its own tag. You don't need a psuedoselector:

```
$("select").change(function () { ... });
```

Comment: Ah, figures it would be something simple like that. Thanks for reading the post. :) Cannot select an answer for 8 minutes, however I will select this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that all you want to do is use the select box that was changed, in this case you can do this

```
$(":input, input:checkbox, .selectedMenu").change(function() {
   var $el = $(this);
   alert($el.val());
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the actual question. I know quite a bit of jQuery, I am trying to figure out the best way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a focused class:

```
$(":input, input:checkbox, .selectedMenu").change(function() {
    $(".focused").removeClass("focused");
    this.addClass("focused");
    //Some Code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put this as a comment but I'm not allowed to... Maybe I misunderstood your question, but what about:

```
$(":input, input:checkbox, select")
```